# win32 (Desktop Duplication API) IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput() results in Access Violation within dxgi.dll

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, direct3d11, dxgi

I'm writing a small c++ app that uses Desktop Duplication API to get the display output. I've never done c programming before, and I got to where I am by staring at the win32 API documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")
#include <roapi.h>
//#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")
#include <dxgi1_2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    cout << RoInitialize(RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED);

    // intermediate variables for casting
    IDXGIOutput* pDisplay_old;

    IDXGIFactory1* pFactory;
    IDXGIAdapter1* pGPU;
    IDXGIOutput1* pDisplay;

    IDXGIOutputDuplication* pCapture;
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC captureDesc;

    // create factory
    if (CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)&pFactory) != S_OK) return 1;

    // get GPU
    if (pFactory -> EnumAdapters1(0, &pGPU) != S_OK) return 1;

    // get display
    if (pGPU -> EnumOutputs(0, &pDisplay_old) != S_OK) return 1;
    pDisplay = (IDXGIOutput1*)pDisplay_old;


    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
    IDXGIResource* pFrame;

    HRESULT captureResult;
    do
    {
        // create capture

       // cout << pDisplay -> DuplicateOutput(pGPU, &pCapture);
        //return 0;
        if (pDisplay -> DuplicateOutput(pGPU, &pCapture) != S_OK) return 1;
        pCapture -> GetDesc(&captureDesc);

        cout << captureDesc.ModeDesc.Width << ' ' << captureDesc.ModeDesc.Height;

        do
        {
            captureResult = pCapture -> AcquireNextFrame(2000, &frameInfo, &pFrame);
            if (captureResult == S_OK)
            {

                cout << "HI";

                captureResult = pCapture -> ReleaseFrame();
            }
            else if (captureResult == DXGI_ERROR_ACCESS_LOST) break;
            else return 1;
        }
        while (true);
    }
    while (true);

}
```

I'm using visual studio 2022 witn only "desktop development with c++" enabled, on windows 11 insider build: 22623.1037 ni_release on a regular home PC with display, beyboard, mouse, etc

The code worked fine until DuplicateOutput(), when it complained E_NOINTERFACE. I'm certain there is an interface since index 0 for EnumAdapters1 and EnumOutputs are where the desktop is displayed, and I obviously have a display attached with the desktop. According to this guy https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041213-00/?p=37043, I need marshalling and apartments or something, so after more research, I tried RoInitialize() with both RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED and RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED. Now, DuplicateOutput throws this exception

[image]

It seems to happen within the library itself, which makes me think that it's either not my fault or I really messed something up, probably the latter.

I'm really confused now, and would like some assistance, thanks!

EDIT: I replaced "pDisplay = (IDXGIOutput1*)pDisplay_old;" with "pDisplay_old -> QueryInterface(&pDisplay);", and I'm back to E_NOINTERFACE, but I think I'm on the right track, how do I fix this error?

EDIT2: I looked at a related question [AcquireNextFrame not working (Desktop Duplication API & D3D11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481467/acquirenextframe-not-working-desktop-duplication-api-d3d11), and followed the answer to add D3D11CreateDevice to my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    // intermediate variables for casting
    IDXGIOutput* pDisplay_old;

    IDXGIFactory1* pFactory;
    IDXGIAdapter* pGPU;
    ID3D11Device* pD3DDevice;
    IDXGIDevice* pDevice;
    IDXGIOutput1* pDisplay;

    IDXGIOutputDuplication* pCapture;
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC captureDesc;

    // create DXGI factory
    if (CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)&pFactory) != S_OK) return 1;

    // get GPU adapter
    if (pFactory -> EnumAdapters(0, &pGPU) != S_OK) return 2;

    // create D3D11 device
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL D3DFeatures [6]
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };
    cout << D3D11CreateDevice(pGPU, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, 0, D3DFeatures, sizeof(D3DFeatures), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &pD3DDevice, NULL, NULL); //!= S_OK) return 3;
    return 0;

    // get DXGI device from that
    pD3DDevice -> QueryInterface(&pDevice);

    // get display
    if (pGPU -> EnumOutputs(0, &pDisplay_old) != S_OK) return 4;
    pDisplay_old -> QueryInterface(&pDisplay);


    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
    IDXGIResource* pFrame;

    HRESULT captureResult;
    do
    {
        // create capture

        cout << pDisplay -> DuplicateOutput(pD3DDevice, &pCapture);
        return 0;
        if (pDisplay -> DuplicateOutput(pGPU, &pCapture) != S_OK) return 5;
        pCapture -> GetDesc(&captureDesc);

        cout << captureDesc.ModeDesc.Width << ' ' << captureDesc.ModeDesc.Height;

        do
        {
            captureResult = pCapture -> AcquireNextFrame(2000, &frameInfo, &pFrame);
            if (captureResult == S_OK)
            {

                cout << "HI";

                captureResult = pCapture -> ReleaseFrame();
            }
            else if (captureResult == DXGI_ERROR_ACCESS_LOST) break;
            else return 6;
        }
        while (true);
    }
    while (true);
```

D3D11CreateDevice seems like a complex function and for me it keeps complaining invalid_arg. I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: `pDisplay = (IDXGIOutput1*)pDisplay_old;` is wrong, you must always use `QueryInterface` to get an interface from another. And you don't need RoInitialize.

Comment: I replaced it with "pDisplay_old -> QueryInterface(&pDisplay);", and I'm back to E_NOINTERFACE, but I think I'm on the right track, how do I fix this error?

Comment: I don't get E_NOINTERFACE (you shouldn't) on this QueryInterface call. What is wrong then is DuplicateOutput expects a Direct3D device, not an adapter interface reference.

Comment: I've worked on it and updated the post above

Comment: Your code is wrong again, use `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN` if you pass an adapter as 1st arg (or ask for hardware and pass nullptr as 1st arg) and use `ARRAYSIZE(D3DFeatures)`, not `sizeof(D3DFeatures)` as 6th arg. Use DirectX Debug Layer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/ to ease debugging

Answer (score 0):

The solution was provided in the comments:

> `pDisplay = (IDXGIOutput1*)pDisplay_old;` is wrong, you must always use `QueryInterface` to get an interface from another. And you don't need RoInitialize. –
> [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) [Jan 1 at 9:11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972883/win32-desktop-duplication-api-idxgioutput1duplicateoutput-results-in-acces/75079617#comment132306126_74972883)

> I replaced it with "pDisplay_old -> QueryInterface(&pDisplay);", and I'm back to E_NOINTERFACE, but I think I'm on the right track, how do I fix this error? –
> [Tiger Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20782194/tiger-yang) [Jan 4 at 16:54](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972883/win32-desktop-duplication-api-idxgioutput1duplicateoutput-results-in-acces/75079617#comment132367453_74972883)

> I don't get E_NOINTERFACE (you shouldn't) on this QueryInterface call. What is wrong then is DuplicateOutput expects a Direct3D device, not an adapter interface reference. –
> [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) [Jan 4 at 17:18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972883/win32-desktop-duplication-api-idxgioutput1duplicateoutput-results-in-acces/75079617#comment132367957_74972883)

> I've worked on it and updated the post above –
> [Tiger Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20782194/tiger-yang) [Jan 7 at 1:51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972883/win32-desktop-duplication-api-idxgioutput1duplicateoutput-results-in-acces/75079617#comment132418821_74972883)

> Your code is wrong again, use `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN` if you pass an adapter as 1st arg (or ask for hardware and pass nullptr as 1st arg) and use `ARRAYSIZE(D3DFeatures)`, not `sizeof(D3DFeatures)` as 6th arg. Use DirectX Debug Layer [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/… walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) to ease debugging –
> [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) [Jan 7 at 7:36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972883/win32-desktop-duplication-api-idxgioutput1duplicateoutput-results-in-acces/75079617#comment132420692_74972883)